What is Hardest to Forecast / Most Likely to be Forecast Wrong, and Easiest / Most Likely to be Right?
Among the common weather forecast variables:

Temperature
Wind Speed
Wind Direction
Precipitation
Cloud coverage
... other variables?

Which ones are the most robust when forecast and which ones are very hard to predict or likely to deviate from the forecast?

the answer to this question depends on what area the forecast is made for.

This question is too general.  Perhaps if more specifics about a real example were provided, it would be reopened.  Factors such as location, altitude, model used, time regime, forecast day, etc. influence model performance.  Furthermore, models are always wrong, so we compute the amount of model error, bias, or other performance metric.

Variables that are Robust:

Temperature: It is a large-scale atmospheric condition and can be well observed and least errored with.

Wind Direction: The wind patterns are determined with high and low atmospheric pressure which is a crucial factor in determining the direction of the wind. As the atmospheric pressure doesn't change suddenly, they have stable patterns

Cloud Coverage: The cloud moments can be observed through satellite and can be pretty to the mark due to the same.


Variables that are Harder to Predict:

Precipitation: This factor highly depends on microphysical processes that are highly sensitive to the condition and hard to predict accurately cause it can fluctuate as no condition can be constant.

Wind Speed: Wind speed depends on the landscape it is observed at like in mountain or coastal areas we cannot say what can be the exact speed or speed range of the wind due to local effects. No to mention the small-scale features, like turbulence and gusts, are hard to resolve in models.



Not sure who downvoted you but I'd like to know why! Thanks for the answer.

looks like ChatGPT output

Thanks for appreciation!
@f.thorpe No, this is what I wrote from my research on the web, not every categorized answer is written by  ChatGPT. Let the Stack Overflow community decide if it is AI-generated.

This answer exhibits many of the characteristics not only of an AI-generated answer but also a hallucinogenic AI-generated answer. In other words, it is not only AI-generated, it is wrong.

You really think it's ai generated despite the errors and broken English?
